# VBA to Copy and Past into next blank cell within a set range

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below vba code created to copy and paste data. The report I'm creating captures historical data to be updated every hour. I need to be able to paste into the next available cell below B10 but cannot figure out how to do that, any suggestions? Thanks!

```
Range("A7").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B10").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

The code assumes that you want the value in cell "A7" to be sent to the first available(blank) cell below B10:

```
Sub Next_Available()

Dim nextAvailableCell As Long

nextAvailableCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row + 1, 11)
Range("B" & nextAvailableCell) = Range("A7")

End Sub
```